# How to add auto image watermark in orchard CMS?

Tags: image, orchardcms, watermark

I use Orchard cms. I want when images uploaded, the images get watermark automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

To add watermark automatically, you have to add a `OnPublished` handler for `ImagePart` as following:

```cs
OnPublished<ImagePart>((context, part) => {
    var mediaPart = part.As<MediaPart>();
    // Here you can add watermark code
});
```

If you want to add the watermark on the original uploaded image, you have to call it from the handler  directly, but if you want to use media processing module mechanism (Which will keep the original image as is, and create a new one with filters applied and save it in `_Profiles` folder), then you can add a new implementation for `IImageFilterProvider`to add a new filter for Orchard media processing pipeline.

Finally, I recommend you to use `ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark` plugin to achieve this, because Orchard already use `ImageResizer` component as default image processing framework.

**Update:** Please refer to this [link](http://www.mdameer.com/blog/image-watermark-filter) for complete implementation, or this [repo](https://github.com/mdameer/Mdameer.Watermark) for source code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by providing a custom implementation of `IImageFilterProvider`. Search for this interface in the solution, you will find a `ResizeFilter` and `FormatFilter` in the `Orchard.MediaProcessing` module as an example.

Also, there are some articles like http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/developing-custom-image-filters-in-orchard-cms.